# How to get the settings and how to change settings using adb commands

Tags: java, android, adb

I am working on a project where I have to retrieve the settings of an Android phone and then change it from command prompt only using adb shell.
Actually I don't know which adb command to use to get the details like SW version, current ringtone, MAC address and which to change. If anyone know that please let me know.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the follow commands:

```
adb shell  cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address #mac address
adb get-serialno                            #serial number
adb shell cat /data/misc/wifi/*.conf        #wifi passward
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. Is there any way to change the ringtone using adb commands and where ringtones are stored.

Comment: maybe [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/how-to-install-a-ringtone-into-internal-memory)